# Changing Class TableViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController`, with some cells. The cells have different background color and text in them. While testing the application their was no problem, but I needed to add a class to the `TableViewController`, so I went to the "custom class" tab and typed in the class, After that, my `TableViewController` just loads up empty. Why is that?

It only happens when I change the class.

Comment: check the data source "number of section" & "number of row" it may nil

Comment: We need the code please.

Comment: double check:

- your custom class exists in the project and you did not mistyped its name
- your custom class inherits from UITableViewController
- dataSource and delegate properties of your tableView are set up correctly to instances that implements UITableViewDataSource protocol and UITableViewDelegate protocol correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

in you custom class you need to implement the data sources as below :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return self.yourArray.count;}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
customCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textlabel.text = @"hi";

return cell;}
```